# How to fix DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET on an Android tablet?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, dns

What I notice:

I can't connect on my **tablet** to the Internet in applications (Android Chrome, Youtube app, Facebook, etc.) My tablet says it is connected to the Wireless router. The router seems to be OK, *my phone can connect* to and get access to the Internet, **my tablet fails** to go online, Chrome reports `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`, other apps say that my device is offline.

I have set up a webserver on my computer connected to the same network and my tablet can connect to it via the IP address and port number of the http server, which makes me conclude that my tablet has some DNS related problem.

If I try to access some website via its IP address e.g. `23.21.146.13` (wdl.org, World Digital Library) the Chrome browser reports `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`.

Steps I have already taken:

- Restarted the tablet
- Shutdown for longer than 10mins as a recommended way for flushing DNS
- Chrome Cache cleared
- Removed the Wifi-Network from the list of Wireless networks and reconnected
- Tried connecting to the router with a manually set static IP, made no difference (but with DHCP the tablet was not showing an IP)
- rebooted router

Some device info:

```
Model: Asus ME173X
Android version: 4.2.2
Kernel version: 3.4.5
Chrome version: 55.0.2883.91
```

My desktop computer and my smartphone have no problem connecting the Internet via the same router.